# How can I know that a special app is running right now

Tags: ios

Recently I need to develop an app that has a feature like this
If I download an app from the `App Store`,I want to know that whether the app has ever launched, Or how can I make sure that this app is running right now(no matter it's in the background or it's active)?

Now I can get all installed apps using `LSApplicationWorkspace` & `LSApplicationProxy`

And I can also get the running progresses right now using `<sys/sysctl.h>`'s stuff which could only provide me the `progressName` (probably its named with the app's project name)

Can anyone else help me with this?

Comment: using "sys/sysctl.h " to get running progress